# Should I flag something as spam even though it answers the question?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, spam

Going through the First Post review today, I got [this review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/16777859) recommending software that (based on a Google search with his name and the company name) I think the poster's associated with.

I skipped the review because I wasn't sure what to do... Normally for bad answers to bad questions we're supposed to skip the review and flag the question, but spam is treated more harshly than the normal bad answer/question (he didn't disclose his affiliation).

I did flag the question, but should I have flagged this answer as spam?  The case could be made he answered the poor question with what it was asking for.

Comment: The relevance of the product and the way the question is phrased plays the key role in deciding what to do. Makoto's right on spot. Your case is a typical one and the preferred approach, whether or not there's any affiliation disclosed in the answer, is to close the question instead.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The answer doesn't quite have the same texture as "spam".  From what I can see of the product, it at least attempts to answer the question as posed, and isn't *just* meant to promote the product.

However, **the question is critically flawed in that it's asking for recommendations.**  The answerer made the mistake of giving them what they asked for even though that's ***not*** the kind of answer we want here.

I would personally have downvoted it if I saw this in review, then voted to close the parent question.  Recommendation questions have no place here.

Comment: This kind of a situation's why recommendation requests were banned in the first place, right (attracting opinionated answers, spam, and borderline spam)?

Comment: @EJoshuaS because answers to these questions are indistinguishable from spam? Yeah.

Comment: @EJoshuaS worth noting that since you thought that answerer hides connection to the product this is still a flaggable abuse (per [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion) they must disclose affiliation). Though if it is not easy to see for those who will handle your flag, you could use custom flag instead of spam and provide explanation of why you think the user is affiliated in the flag message

Comment: @gnat That's a good point, I'll remember it for next time. There was no disclosure. I think a custom flag would have been best so I could explain why I thought he was associated with the product.